# How to use Chai.should in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have a code backend:

```
var addSupplierQuota = function (req, res) {
    var data = req.body.object;

    supplierquota.create(data) //add
    .then(function (_data) {
      res.json({
        statusCode: 0,
        data: _data
      })
    }, function (_err) {
      res.json({
        statusCode: -1,
        err: _err
      });
    })
}
```

and a test function using mocha and chai:

```
it.only('supplier/addSupplierQuota',function(done){
    chai.request(server)
      .post('supplier/addSupplierQuota')
      .send({
        object: {
          supplierid: 1,
          survey_id: faker.random.number(10),
          quota: faker.random.number(),
          startdate: faker.date.recent(),
          lk_recordstatus: 1
        }
      })
      .end(function(err, res){
        if(err)
          throw err
        res.should.be.json
        res.should.have.status(200)
        res.body.should.have.property('statusCode').equal(0)
        res.body.should.have.property('data').be.a('object')

        console.log('res: ', res.body)
        done()
      });
});
```

In this case, I've only used chai.should for case:

```
res.json({
  statusCode: 0,
  data: _data
})
```

But, with following case I didn't:

```
res.json({
  statusCode: -1,
   err: _err
});
```

I want to use chai.should for 2 cases with 1 time. How can I do?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with that you want to use it with 2 cases? Like 2 Assertions for 2 Requests in the same test?

Comment: I want 2 Assertions for 2 Responses in the same test for both when res.statusCode = -1 and res.statusCode = 0